# How to downgrade from laravel 9.2 to laravel 8?

Tags: php, laravel, shopify

I wanted to use the the

```
composer require osiset/laravel-shopify
```

but the issue is I'm running in laravel 8, I wanted to downgrade my laravel 9.2 to laravel 8.0 but when I tried downgrading it by changing the composer.json into

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.3|^8.0",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.4.1",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0.3",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
        "laravel/framework": "^8.0",
        "laravel/passport": "^10.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.5|dev-develop",
        "paragonie/random_compat": "2.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.2",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^5.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.3.3"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    }
}
```

but I'm getting these kind of errors

In Facade.php line 178:

Facade does not implement getFacadeAccessor method.

Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1

I'm new to laravel and  I don't know what to do... thank you

Comment: Any important content already in your L9 project? If not just install a new L8 in a different folder

Comment: Yes I have important files already

Comment: I would suggest contacting the developer of the package to add Laravel 9 support.  In some cases they just need to change the composer json file.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the version you want easily by running

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel="5.1.*" myProject
```

Comment: not the answer..

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, Degrade your php version from 8.1 to 7.3.

Secondly, Create new laravel project with following instruction.

- composer create-project laravel/laravel:^8.0 example-app

Thirdly, move blade, controller, route, model and so on from old project to new project.